# How to deal with a lost OpenPGP signature key?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, pgp, openpgp

My laptop crashed and I cannot uncover the files including my OpenPGP signature key, and I can no longer deploy to the central Maven repository.

The question is can I generate an new key pair and distribute the public key to key server like `hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net`? How to revoke my previous public key?

Comment: lol, seems like you lose the ability to publish to your old namespace., java package publishing is a joke compared to npm. I think I will just push to a public git repository and use jitpack.io Any other alternatives to this bureaucracy are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to revoke my previous public key?

Never lose access to your private key. If you have not generated a revocation certificate in advance, you cannot even revoke your key. [You haven't even got a chance to remove the key from the key server network.](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/67633/19837)

With other words: you can't do anything about the key you lost, unless in some time in future it is possible to brute-force the key (or crack it using other methods).

> The question is can I generate an new key pair and distribute the public key to key server like `hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net`?

For a new key, you'll have to start publishing it again of course (using the SKS pool is a good choice and will make sure the key spreads throughout the key server network quickly). With a new key, you'll lose all certifications, of course. You might have to register the key somewhere in the Maven repository again.

At the same time, pre-generate a revocation certificate [and put it in some safe place](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/65953/19837) to be sure if some disaster happens again. And make sure to have some reasonable, automated and verified backup before you start doing anything on your computer.